# Twitter Bootstrap multiple accordions but only one open panel at a time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 Twitter Bootstrap accordions on my page, each one set up like this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseOne1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseTwo1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseThree1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `id`'s of the accordions are like the one displayed above, so `#accordion1`, `#accordion2` and `#accordion3`. The same counts for the panels per accordion.

How can I alter this set up so that only one panel can be open at a time? At the moment, one panel *per accordion* can be open at a time, which is not my desired behaviour.

**DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamonic/yd4mbhtc/)**

Comment: Couldn't you just use one accoordion for all in this case?

Comment: @Sebsemillia I could, but the thing is I have 3 categories within these accordions, so placing all of the panels in just one accordion would make the clear separation of these categories dissapear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseTwo1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseThree1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne2">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseTwo2">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseThree2">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne3">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseTwo3">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseThree3">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what *exactly* you've changed?

Comment: Actually i combined the 'data-parent'

Comment: I noticed in the time between my comment and yours. Does as asked, perfect!

Comment: Thank you Dreamonic :) Have a nice time

Comment: verry good! TANKS! i have changed this to be a class instead of a list of id (i was adding panels dynamically). added "specialGroup" in panel-group class  and reference .specialGroup in data-parrent

Comment: Right solution, bad answer! It's not a ready made solution we're looking for, so much as how to arrive at the solution, and why it works.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is good, but doesn't exactly answer what they *did* in order to make that work.

[In this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/ontupk1e/) you can see the bare-minimum code that's needed, which is:

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="panels">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panels" data-target="#firstPanel">
             <h4>First header</h4>    
        </div>
        <div id="firstPanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div>Content.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panels" data-target="#secondPanel">
             <h4>Second header</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="secondPanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div>Other content.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that each `panel` has a `data-parent` which targets the parent `div` with the ID `#panels`.

*That* is the magic sauce you need.

Comment: This solved all of my accordion problems. I was simply missing the data-parent props. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Add this javascript:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $otherPanels = $(this).parents('.panel-group').siblings('.panel-group');
    $('.collapse',$otherPanels).removeClass('in');
});
```

Comment: The answer on the top is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply do something like this:

```
jQuery('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery('.collapse').removeClass('in');    
});
```