# Two different bootstrap accordion trigger each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, conflict

As you can on the example bootlint is fine and all IDs unique but two diffrent collapsable accordion triggers each other. Still looking for solution.

Live example : http://codepen.io/bertanyaman/pen/NNOLyG

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
                                aria-controls="collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"
                        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">Collapsible Group Item #3</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne2">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
                                href="#collapseOne2" aria-expanded="true"
                                aria-controls="collapseOne2">Collapsible Group Item
              #1</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in"
                        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne2">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo2"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">Collapsible Group Item #2</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree2">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree2"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree2">Collapsible Group Item #3</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree2">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code example on CodePen is using TWBS 4-alpha2 versions of the css and js.  If you revert to TWBS 3.3.6 (and JQuery 1) then your code works.

See this prior question [25359335](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359335/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-accordions-but-only-one-open-panel-at-a-time), and it's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamonic/yd4mbhtc/)

I copied this working code to your CodePen and it broke too, but then I reverted to 3.3.6 and it worked again.

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18824) in V4

```
<sorry> :( </sorry>
```