# Accordion not auto collapsing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a accordion which is working absolutely fine but what I need is to open only one tab at a time, means when one tab is opened then another tab should be closed.

Currently you can see that we can open all the tabs by clicking on tab links.

Code here

```
<div id="accordion" class="checkout">    
<div class="panel checkout-step">
    <div class="head" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <img src="{{ asset('bundles/leaderboxfrontfront/img/1.png') }}" alt="">
        <div id="bubble">
            <h1><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" > MON PROJET</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="form-zone">
            <div class="content">
                Some content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel checkout-step">
    <div class="head" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <img src="{{ asset('bundles/leaderboxfrontfront/img/3.png') }}" alt="">
        <div id="bubble">
            <h1><a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"  > je choisis mon centre</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="form-zone">
            <div class="content">
                Some content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to add `your code`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap multiple accordions but only one open panel at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359335/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-accordions-but-only-one-open-panel-at-a-time)

Comment: Thanks @BigMacMenu . I think I fixed it