# Accordion close tab when another is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I have created an accordion, but I want it to close the tabs when another one is clicked. At the moment, it opens the tabs, but when another is clicked, it doesn't close the last one...

This is the code:

```
<button class="accordion">Accordion</button>
<div class="panel">Content</div>

<button class="accordion">Accordion 2</button>
<div class="panel">Content</div>
```

[This is the code working](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyZeaE)

Comment: See my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42905641/4826740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below Accordion and download first js and css on giving path on link in html

```js
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({event:false, active :false});

var noSections = $("#accordion h3").length-1;

$("h3").each(function (index, element)
{
    $(element).click(function()
    {
       if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))
       {
           if(index < noSections)
              $("#accordion").accordion('option','active',index + 1);
           else
              $("#accordion").accordion('option','active',index - 1);
       }
       else
       {
          $("#accordion").accordion('option','active',index);
       }
   });
});
```

```css
.accordionStyle{
 position: relative !important;
 width:500px !important; 
 margin: 30px auto !important;
}

.accordionStyle h3{
 padding-left:35px; 
}

p{
 font-size:12px 
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
    padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
    min-height: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.accordionStyle h3 {
    padding-left: 35px;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #ffffff url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion" class="accordionStyle">
  <h3>Accordion 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    test1
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Accordion  2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
   test2
    </p>
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just "close" all accordion pages in the click event.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    for(var it of elems) {
      it.classList.remove("active");
      it.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }

    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });

}
```

[Live demo.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/paXYGO)

Comment: Probably you're using an outdated browser.

Change the for(... of ...) to for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++)