# Bootstrap accordion hide when another open

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am trying to do accordion when one is open than other will be close. 
 here is my js :

```
 $(".uv-accordinaton-list").on( "click", function() {
   $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
   $(this).find(">:first-child");
   if($(this).find(">:first-child").text() == "+") {
      $(this).find(">:first-child").text("-");
      $(this).find("h2").addClass("hilighted");
   } else {
   $(this).find(">:first-child").text("+");
   $(this).find("h2").removeClass("hilighted");
 }
```

The live link is : https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/vWxGLK

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap multiple accordions but only one open panel at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359335/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-accordions-but-only-one-open-panel-at-a-time)

Comment: Its not same. I use Plus minus on one panel on js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this

```
  $(".uv-accordinaton-list").on( "click", function() {
    $(".uv-accordinaton-list>:first-child").text("+");
    $(".uv-accordinaton-list h2").removeClass("hilighted");
    $(".uv-accordition-detail").slideUp();
    if($(this).find(">:first-child").text() == "+") {
     $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
       $(this).find(">:first-child").text("-");
      $(this).find("h2").addClass("hilighted");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code:

```
$(".uv-accordinaton-list") . on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").find(".uv-accordition-detail").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("display") == 'block') {
            $(this).slideUp(200);
            $(this).closest("li").find("h2").removeClass("hilighted");
            $(this).closest("li").find(".uv-right-arrow").text("+");
            return false;
        }
    });
    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    $(this).find(">:first-child");
    if ($(this).find(">:first-child").text() == "+") {
        $(this).find(">:first-child").text("-");
        $(this).find("h2").addClass("hilighted");
    } else {
        $(this).find(">:first-child").text("+");
        $(this).find("h2").removeClass("hilighted");
    }
});
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/rohitmittal/pen/WPdbbJ

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function toggleIcon(e) {
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find(".more-less")
            .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    }
    $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
    $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

```css
/*******************************
* ACCORDION WITH TOGGLE ICONS
* Does not work properly if "in" is added after "collapse".
*******************************/
 .panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
 }

 .panel-default > .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
 }

 .panel-title {
  font-size: 14px;
 }

 .panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .more-less {
  float: right;
  color: #212121;
 }

 .panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
 }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
 background-color: #26a69a;
}

.demo {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.demo-footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #212121;
 text-align: center;
}

.demo-footer > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container demo">

 
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      Collapsible Group Item #1
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
       Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      Collapsible Group Item #2
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
     Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      Collapsible Group Item #3
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
    <div class="panel-body">
     Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div><!-- panel-group -->
 
 
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  In addition to providing code, please consider adding a summary of what you changed and why it works.